# Animate scrollable widgets to fill one another's space on scroll in another widget

Tags: flutter

Here is an app with three main widgets: sized box and two scrollable `ListView`s, one inside `SizedBox()` and another inside `Expanded()`.

What I am trying to do is for BottomList to move upwards and occupy the place of TopList when it is scrolled, and move to BottomList's original position if TopList is scrolled. How do I achieve this?

MRE:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('two scrolls')),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // Widget1: this box should stay in place
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
          // TopList: this box should shrink to the top until it hits some minimum height, on scroll in BottomList
          // If it is scrolled after Widget3 took all the space, expand its contents to bottom to a set height.
          SizedBox(
            // has half of remaining height
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5 - kToolbarHeight,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(height: 16, thickness: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
          // BottomList: on scroll, should expand upwards to fill the space of TopList until it hits TopList_minHeight, then scroll as usual.
          // On scroll of TopList, should move to it's original position.
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to the `ScrollController` that adjust the height of the Top list widget.
Note that you need to manually dispose ScrollController in this case.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final ScrollController topScrollController;
  late final ScrollController bottomScrollController;
  double topOffset = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    topScrollController = ScrollController();
    topScrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        topOffset = 0;
      });
    });

    bottomScrollController = ScrollController();
    bottomScrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        topOffset = bottomScrollController.offset;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    topScrollController.dispose();
    bottomScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topMaxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 -
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5 -
        kToolbarHeight;
    const topMinHeight = 50.0;
    double height = topOffset <= 200
        ? topMaxHeight
        : max(topMaxHeight + 200 - topOffset, topMinHeight);

    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('two scrolls')),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // Widget1: this box should stay in place
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
          // TopList: this box should shrink to the top until it hits some minimum height, on scroll in BottomList
          // If it is scrolled after Widget3 took all the space, expand its contents to bottom to a set height.

          SizedBox(
            // has half of remaining height
            height: height,
            child: ListView(
              controller: topScrollController,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(height: 16, thickness: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
          // BottomList: on scroll, should expand upwards to fill the space of TopList until it hits TopList_minHeight, then scroll as usual.
          // On scroll of TopList, should move to it's original position.
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              controller: bottomScrollController,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  height: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did not know there is `offset` getter in ScrollController! That's what I need, thank you